# Firebase auth custom token iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, vk, vk-sdk

I am trying to add to my app VK authorization with `Firebase SDK`.

When user authorization finished, I try to pass token to Firebase.

```
func vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult(result: VKAuthorizationResult!){

        let tokenString = result.token.description
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(tokenString) { (user, error) in
            // ...

        }
    }
```

> Error: [1] (null)  "NSLocalizedDescription" : "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."

Can I use Firebase with custom auth without running server?

Comment: can you post your code for create custom token ....

Comment: i get token from VK servers, in result

Comment: no you have to create token with `firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid);` for firebase ... then its working for you

Comment: I cant find any createCustomToken method. in documentation i saw it only in server configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Firebase Doc. [Create custom tokens using the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens),

I would say that you need to use `createCustomToken()` method for this.. you can not use your VK servers token to signIn with firebase ... you need to generate token for firebase with `createCustomToken()` method.

```
 var uid = "some-uid";
 var customToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
```

May this work for you

Comment: can i use VK authorization with Firebase without running server? as i understand, createCustomToken method from documentation is only for my own server

Comment: @EugeneStrelnikov I dont think so ... but I never tried that and dont know much about it

Comment: Hey @EICaptainv2.0, I am trying to log my user in with username and password only, like in Instagram, how can I do this? I am kinda new to swift and I kinda didn't understand your answer, hope you can help me out! :)